# Multiple Pics in \TikZset?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is it possible to have multiple pictures within a single `\tikzset` command? In my MWEs I try to create an X and an O pic.

E.g. This did not work.

```
\tikzset
 {
  X/.pic={\draw (-5mm,5mm)--(5mm,-5mm) (-5mm,-5mm)--(5mm,5mm);}}
  O/.pic={\draw circle (0.3cm);}
 }
```

E.g. This worked.

```
\tikzset{X/.pic={\draw (-5mm,5mm)--(5mm,-5mm) (-5mm,-5mm)--(5mm,5mm);}}
\tikzset{O/.pic={\draw circle (0.3cm);}}
```

Comment: Using `},` instead of `}}`?

Comment: Where would those go and why?

Comment: @egreg meant that you have an extra `}` at the end of `X/.pic={\draw (-5mm,5mm)--(5mm,-5mm) (-5mm,-5mm)--(5mm,5mm);}}`. Remove it. Now `tikzset` ends after first `pic`.

Comment: Each `.pic` (or `.style`) must be enclosed in braces; to separate consecutive `.pic`s use a comma: `\tikzset
 {
  X/.pic={\draw (-5mm,5mm)--(5mm,-5mm) (-5mm,-5mm)--(5mm,5mm);},
  O/.pic={\draw circle (0.3cm);}
 }`

Comment: Not sure this is entirely relevant but you can also subgroup pics. e.g. `\tikzset{figures/.is family, figures/.cd, the good/.pic={...}, the bad/.pic={...}, the ugly/.pic={...}, ...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\tikzset` recieves a *comma separated* list of options as argument. In the simpler form, those options are lists of *comma-separated* pairs of the form `key = value`, for example:

```
\tikzset{>=latex,shorten >= 4pt}
```

but in more elaborate situations you can also have styles, `pic` paths and other stuff in the argument of `\tikzset`; in any case, one of the important things to remember is that the argument is a *comma separated* list, so if you want to have several `pic`s (styles, key-value pairs,...) in the options for `\tikzset`, thet should be separated by a comma:

```
\tikzset{
  X/.pic={
    \draw 
      (-5mm,5mm) -- (5mm,-5mm) 
      (-5mm,-5mm)--(5mm,5mm);
  },
  O/.pic={
    \draw circle (0.3cm);
  }
}
```